# How to find which application send which file on server in android

Tags: android

I know about the TrafficStats Class which can tell about the Network uses by an application in Android. Now I want to know which application sends which file on server from the device. Is there any way to find this. Is there any Android API which can do this task or can help to do this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sniffing with a man in the middle / fiddler to know what is reached (see traffic), and you can uncompile apk builds of android applications so it means that you can see what the application do, but I didn't see how can you know directly from wich application it comes.

More info for fiddle:
http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not want to uncompile the apk, because i do not want this info about a particular app. I want to know about any Android API which can do this work.

Comment: No, this API gives details about connexions but not all datas transmitted by all applications (I mean all informations of all datas) otherwise this would be a big security issue, isn't it?

Comment: Yes that's why i want to create this app which can tell the user about all apps which application steal which information by uploading to their server.

Comment: This is not possible for me ;-) you can make statistics of data consumptionwith hours and so on but know xhat application to what server with what data it is not permitted... or maybe for root devices but well at that point I can't help you sorry